# How to get user presence in java using smack?

Tags: android

I am using smack library for instant messaging and able to get user presence on openfire server but getting null user presence in the code.

using below code to set user presence

```
                Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
                presence.setMode(Presence.Mode.available);
                presence.setStatus("online");
                connection.sendPacket(presence);
```

Using below code for getting user presence

```
    Roster roster = ShareFareScreen.connection.getRoster();
    Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();  
    for (RosterEntry entry : entries) {
        System.out.println(String.format("Buddy:%1$s - Status:%2$s", 
                entry.getName(), entry.getStatus())+"      "+entry.getUser());
        System.out.println("###"+roster.getPresence(entry.getUser()).getMode());
    }
```

Getting "null" user presence.Please help me out.
Thanks in advance.